# Can I use a DC battery cable rated at 600 A to connect a 63 A main AC breaker to a 40 A RCCB in my distribution panel?

Tags: batteries, wiring, cables, panel

I've read that for low-voltage (less than 400 V) applications,  the main difference between DC and AC wire is basically in the (temperature) rating of the cable sheath.

If this is true, then the heating of the wire should be proportional to the amount of current and its gauge/X-sectional area, right? It then follows that using a larger diameter wire, in this case 6 gauge battery wire rated for 600 A (peak cranking) should be able to be used to connect a 63 A mains breaker with a 40 A RCCB inside a distribution panel, no?

My main motivation is cost. 6AWG/14mm AC cable is expensive especially when purchased in shorter lengths, which I would need for wiring a DP. I have some spare battery cables so would very much like to use these as long as I don't risk burning down my house.

I would appreciate it if somebody more qualified and experienced could help me with these questions.

Comment: This is not about if you can use it or not, it is whether the cable is rated for that job, and whether regulations allow it. If you don't know the voltage rating of the cable, why even consider it? Purchasing the right cable that the regulations allow is a cheap insurance.

Comment: It may work fine until you come to make even an unrelated claim on your insurance. If the breach of code is discovered, then no payout. Your cheap cable could suddenly seem to be very expensive indeed.

Comment: Issue will be insulation breakdown voltage of the wire, if it has printed on it a higher voltage than what your using, you may be fine, however for big battery wires, usually they are lucky to be rated over 100V DC.

Comment: Ok thanks. Seems the overwhelming expert consensus is to spring for the AC voltage rated cable. Given the 40A rating of the RCCB, does this group think 10mm2 wire would be sufficient? Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

##### TL;DR The problem here is not the current, it is the voltage.

Stranded wire is fine. In fact, in the US, stranded wire is the *only* type available for 120V/240V installations at larger sizes.

The key question is in this phrase:

> 6 gauge battery wire rated for 600 A (peak cranking)

Specifically, **peak cranking**. That is something which will go on for a few seconds, perhaps intermittently for a couple of minutes if you have trouble starting a car. It does not run at 600A, or anything close to that, for hours at a time.

We then get to the key determining factors - the breakers:

> 63 A mains breaker with a 40 A RCCB

In the US, the equivalent to an RCCB is a GFCI. A GFCI will normally be designed and sold for a particular current rating, but in fact the basics of GFCI - and RCCB, as I understand it - are really independent of the *total* current. They trip based on the *difference* between the current flowing on the attached wires, at a very low level. Presumably a 40A RCCB is rated to handle that much current flowing through it, but it can trip on 0.1A flowing through it if that current is not balanced on the hot/neutral wires.

In the US (and based on "RCCB", this is not in the US, so this may not apply exactly), the usual copper wire sizes (I've never seen aluminum battery wires so I'm assuming these are copper) are:

- 8 AWG = 40A for 60 C termination, 50A for 75 C termination
- 6 AWG = 55A for 60 C termination, 65A for 75 C termination

which means that at least nominally, based on "breakers usually 75 C termination", 6 AWG *should* be perfectly safe for continuous use with a 63A main breaker.

However, there is another issue with "battery wire". Conductor size scales with current, insulation type/thickness scales with *voltage*. A battery cable would not normally need to be rated for 240V, or even 120V. It *might* turn out to be fine, but that is no guarantee. Typical AC wiring is rated for 600V, so it can be used safely in 120V/240V installations + one step up to 480V. Battery wire, in theory, could be rated as low as 15V, though in a quick search I found 50V rating, which makes sense as it would allow for nominal 12V batteries connected to produce 24V or possibly even 48V. But 120V or 240V? No way!

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use it. You won't burn your house if done properly. And the insulation should be enough or it's really very cheap low quality wire. But... it's **really** unprofessional. Sorry.

When you do this kind of job on electrical installations which will last forever, better do it properly and lay some extra bucks for the satisfaction of doing something beautifully.

The biggest problem with battery wires is that they are multi-stranded. You need single strand for main electrical installations. This is very important. In some countries it's allowed to use multi strand wires but a termination must be added to keep all the strands together before inserting them inside the circuit breaker. Yet I don't know the regulation in your country. In any case it looks more professional to use single stranded wires because that's what every professional do.

Somebody talked about fire insurance. If your building burns and the insurance expert finds your battery wires, they will conclude that the installation was not done by a certified electrician. If they find a good cable, they won't think that you did it yourself.
It's also a good investment, the day you or its owner want to sell or lent it.

For very large gauge, only multi-strand exist because it's not convenient to make them single strand. But these strands are very thick in comparison to true multi strand wires.

Multi strand wires must be used only on constantly moving elements.

Comment: Thanks to all for your feedback. Just to provide some context, I'm actually wiring up a DP for use in my retirement farmhouse in the rural Philippines, where compliance with 'official' electrical standards are virtually non-existent. Wiring used is generally under-sized and with very limited choice of wire sizes or if available, super expensive.

Comment: Btw stranded wire is basically all that is available so, what would be the groups' recommendation on what size stranded wire to use to connect the mains breaker to the 40A RCCB?

Comment: @williamc In rural Philipines, it may be acceptable. LOL. For 40A, you should use 6 mm³ (4mm³ if you can't find or afford more, as absolute minimum). Because it's muslti strand, I would use a little be more than 6 mm³.